# Pick up one element and add a CSS rule to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CMS (Joomla) site, with the `®` sign on many places. Instead of going through every module and adding a `span` to it, than making it `superscript`, is there a JS or jQuery code I can use, to pick this sign up and make it superscript?

I know it is a long shot, but if that actually exists it would be super cool.

Thanks.

EDIT: If possible with pure JS as I have a complex slider and including jQuery brings errors

Comment: Is it possible for you to wrap the `®` inside something like `<span class="reg">` or something?

Comment: How ® is generated ? Does your site has any other text along with ® ?

Comment: I would amend the HTML directly. Using JS as a crutch for UI issues is a bad idea.

Comment: Traversing html with javascript to find this symbol is something no one would recommend you. Better to go with wrapping it inside any HTML Tag i.e. span or sup. It will take time but it's more elegant and maintainable solution

Comment: There is always text along with it, and it comes from modules - PHP code mostly

Comment: I don't really know Joomla, but better solution would be replacing it on the server-side, maybe http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rereplacer or something similar would work for you.

Comment: For solving `jQuery` conflicts, please [read this article](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this using JavaScript / jQuery, but it is a very costly function!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").html($("body").html().replace(new RegExp('®', 'g'), '<sup>&reg;</sup>'));
});
```

> **Note 1:** This is terrible in performance!
>
> **Note 2:** This may remove the `events`, so better replace `"body"` with a selector, that has only Rich Text Content!

Solution for **Note 2**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".user-content-area").html($(".user-content-area").html().replace(new RegExp('®', 'g'), '<sup>&reg;</sup>'));
});
```

There may be chances like using `&reg;` for the same. So, for those:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".user-content-area").html($(".user-content-area").html().replace(new RegExp('&reg;', 'gi'), '<sup>&reg;</sup>'));
});
```

There's an alternative version for the regex! You can use `split()` and `join()` too! Instead of:

```
.replace(new RegExp('®', 'g'), '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
```

Change it with:

```
.split('®').join('<sup>&reg;</sup>')
.split('&reg;').join('<sup>&reg;</sup>')
```

> **Note:** This is case sensitive! `:(`

Answer (score 1):

Better use some CSS instead of some javascript for that. 
CSS:

```
.sup { vertical-align: super; }
```

HTML:

```
<span class="sup">&reg;</span>
```

You could easily do a search/replace on many files using Sed

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/\&reg;/<span class=\"sup\">\&reg;<\/span>/g'
```

(note: **not tested!**)